# Change only Homepage URL (Permalink) Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to change only the Homepage/Frontpage of my Wordpress website. I have my Homepage set to "Display your latest Posts" and not Page itself. I'm looking for a way to change a permalink/URL of my "Your Latest Posts" homepage. Is that even possible? I'm using a "Bimber Premium" theme if that helps.

I have tried many different redirection methods and WP Plugins but none has worked.

For example this code in functions.php:

```
function redirect_homepage() {
    if( ! is_home() && ! is_front_page() )
        return;

    wp_redirect( 'http://yoursiteurl.com', 301 );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_homepage' );
```

tldr: wanna change homepage url from https://your-domain.com/ to https://your-domain.com/first/ if the homepage is set to "Show your latest posts" in Homepage settings (WP -> Settings -> Reading -> Your latest posts).